# Documentation with l3doc.cls

Tags: expl3, documentation, l3doc

I have been trying to convert my package documentation from `ltxdoc` to `l3doc`, and I've met several obstacles.

First is getting `\ProvidesExplFile` to work. I tried to do something like this:

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*driver|package>
\GetIdInfo $Id: test.dtx 1.0 2024/02/04 I. M. A. Person <dumb@stupid.com> $
     {description of package}
%</driver|package>
%<*driver>
\ProvidesExplFile{\ExplFileName.dtx}
%</driver>
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
%<package>\RequirePackage{expl3}
%<package>\ProvidesExplPackage{\ExplFileName}
%<*driver|package>
   {\ExplFileDate}{\ExplFileVersion}{\ExplFileDescription}
%</driver|package>
%<*driver>
\documentclass[12pt]{l3doc}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{test.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \title{The \pkg{test} package\thanks{This document corresponds to
%   \textsf{test}~\ExplFileVersion, dated \ExplFileDate.}}
% \author{me}
% \date{\ExplFileDate}
% \maketitle
% \begin{documentation}
% \section{Documentation}
% \end{documentation}
% \iffalse
%<*package>
%<@@=test>
% \fi
%
% \begin{implementation}
% \section{Implementation}
% \end{implementation}
%
% \Finale
% \iffalse
%</package>
% \fi
\endinput
```

However, this results in an error. I was able to get this to work if I use `\ProvidesFile` instead of `ProvidesExplFile`, like this:

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*driver|package>
\GetIdInfo $Id: test.dtx 1.0 2024/01/26 I. M. A. Person <dumb@stupid.com> $
     {description of package}
%</driver|package>
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{\ExplFileName.dtx}
    [\ExplFileDate\space v\ExplFileVersion\space\ExplFileDescription]
%</driver>
%<package>
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
%<package>\RequirePackage{expl3}
%<package>\ProvidesExplPackage{\ExplFileName}
%<package>   {\ExplFileDate}{\ExplFileVersion}{\ExplFileDescription}
%<*driver>
\documentclass[12pt]{l3doc}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{test.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with `\ProvidesFile`, your documentation isn't using the `expl3`-category code regime, is it? I doubt you want to have to input every space throughout your documentation using `~`.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but the team have not used `\GetIdInfo` for a long time: it's retained only as we cannot remove it from `expl3` as it's required for stability.

Comment: @JosephWright What is the preferred mechanism? I am relatively new to expl3, so to a certain extent I'm wandering around in the dark hoping I don't bump into something.

Comment: @Skillmon There's nothing wrong with it, per se, but it seems like what I was doing should have worked, and it didn't. I found a workaround, but I'm trying to do it "right" if there is such a thing.

Comment: I think you might've misunderstood my comment. I understand there is an academic interest in why this didn't work for you and how to fix it, but `\ProvidesExplFile` is meant to be used on files which are (primarily) in that category code regime, something that just seems wrong for documentation. I'd advice you to not use it at all for your `.dtx`.

Comment: @Skillmon Good point. I have encountered some other errors that led me to think perhaps I should be using `\ProvidesExplFile`, but you're right: that would effectively delete the spaces, which is another problem entirely....